# Facing issue while implementing the XATransation implementation with tomcat,mssql,ActiveMQ

Tags: sql-server-2008, datasource, xa

we have a project which is not an XA ,currently trying implementing XA implementaion I have followed the following setps for implementation:
in tomee.xml changed the resoure from

```
<Resource id="paymentsDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
```

to

```
<Resource id="paymentsDS" type="javax.sql.XADataSource" class-name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource">
```

and followed the steps same in the provided document : XA with Microsoft SQL Server requires the MS DTC to be configured correctly, and sqljdbc_xa.dll to be installed. For instructions, please see this Microsoft article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-xa-transactions?view=sql-server-2017

**In tomcat logs I'm observing Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: REPORT_INSTANCE** ,

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: REPORT_INSTANCE `at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) at  org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)

Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: REPORT_INSTANCE'

but didn't have any hsqlDB I'm using mssql

anyone has idea of resolving the issue and do I need to do any further changes.